# How is the output of this circuit RS232?

Tags: serial, rs232, ftdi

I'm trying to design a multi-channel USB-RS232 adaptor ([inspired by this](https://ftdichip.com/products/usb-com232-plus4/)) to go into a larger design. After hunting a little, I found this schematic in the datasheet for FTDI's [FT4232](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT4232H.pdf), which is the chip they use in the aforementioned device, along with a MAX324 on the serial output: [image: FT4232 suggested configuration]

My question is, how does this circuit output RS232? I couldn't find any explanation through the FT4232 datasheet, and the MAX324 is rated up to 16V, but doesn't appear to step up its input voltages, if I'm not mistaken.

Do I need extra circuitry to step the output up to a more standard RS232 voltage (+/-12V or something)?

Comment: Probably wrong part number. Check for MAX3243.

Comment: @user263983 for a transmitter the standard is anything between 5 V and 15 V and -5 V and -15 V. For a receiver it's extended to 3 V and -3 V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *how does this circuit output RS232?*

The specific device is a MAX3241 (not MAX324) and, if you read its [data sheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) you will see that inside the chip are voltage supply circuits that can produce voltage levels suitable for driving an RS232 line: -

[image]

> *Do I need extra circuitry to step the output up to a more standard
> RS232 voltage (+/-12V or something)?*

No.

Comment: Ah brilliant. I couldn't really read the part number through the low-res image in the datasheet. Makes a lot more sense than the MAX324.